# cassandra-stress: URI is not absolute error

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cassandra-stress

I am trying to run cassandra-stress from a bash script:

```bash
HUB_STATUS_YAML="~/some-path/hub_errors.yaml"
COMMAND="cassandra-stress user profile=${HUB_STATUS_YAML} ops(insert=1)"
echo About to run $COMMAND
$COMMAND
```

I end up with the following error: "URI is not absolute".

Comment: Have you checked your file exists at this location and is correctly named? I just spent 10 min having the same error before finally realizing I had typed example.yml instead of example.yaml...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[axelcdv's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036650/cassandra-stress-uri-is-not-asbolute-error/32468307#comment47490617_29036650) concurred with my experience of this problem.

Make sure you spell the file name correctly.

I'm taking DataStax training atm and encountered the same error.
I was spelling the cqlstress.yaml as csqlstress.yaml the "URI is not absolute" error.

Comment: When you use someone else's work product as an answer, typically you should make the answer community wiki.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm taking the training also and I was in the wrong directory.

Comment: this reply is very long time ago, but it saved me today, many thanks.